# What's the first movie to use this technique?

Tags: first-appearance

In Scene 1, a man is telling a group of men about something that happened to him
in the past. In Scene 2, the audience sees a visual representation of the man’s past
experience on the screen. **The character is speaking to his audience to explain what happened
in Scene 2, but the people in Scene 2 cannot hear him even though they see him**:

For example:  In the movie Reservoir Dogs (1992), there is a bar scene where Orange
recounts an event to Joe's Gang. He explains that he had gone to a train station to
pick up a buyer while carrying weed in a carry-on bag. When he went into the restroom,
he found four Los Angeles County sheriffs and a German shepherd dog already there.
They stopped talking when they saw him. **Then it appears that Orange is speaking to the cops,
but he is actually speaking to Joe’s Gang at the bar**:

[image]

Comment: if it helps... [15 Brilliant Flashback Examples for Screenwriters and Filmmakers](https://industrialscripts.com/flashback-examples/) and [about flashbacks](https://screencraft.org/blog/everything-you-need-to-know-about-flashbacks/)

Comment: Removing the 'reservoir-dogs' tag since this is not really a question about this movie.